# How to redirect to current page after clicking alert button

Tags: angular, alert, ngfor

Is there any way where one can redirect to or refresh current page after clicking alert button?

I want my current page reloaded after clicking on alert button, is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your contributions.

Comment: Which is the objective of the refresh?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from doing location.reload(), but you really shouldn't unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Which alert are you using. Is it default alert or some custom made

Comment: to add to @RandomCode href or routerLink attribute with `/` or `./` respectively should work or close to but there should be VERY few cases where this is required. Please explain why you want this behavior first - i'm betting this isn't the answer your looking for.

Comment: I am working on angular CRUD, so after I made post or update request I want actually the ngFor table to get update after the closing the alert box. I will also appreciate contributions in case there is a better way of reloading the table other than refreshing the entire page.

Comment: Cheers to you all!

Comment: It's really hard to guess what is wrong with your code without knowing more about it, but refresh isn't a solution, at least not permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use window.location.reload() to reload your current page.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code there's little help we can provide...

But you basically want something like this: [StackBlitzExample of 2 way binding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-2-way-bind?file=app/app.component.ts)

ts:

```
objectArr = []
//update this array with from your subscribe of the http request
//something like this
update(): void {
    this.{service}.httpRequest().subscribe((result: data[]) => {
        this.objectArr = data; //bind the new data to the array you are using to create the table
    });
}
```

html:

```
<-- your table element -->
<div *ngFor="let obj of objectArr">
```

this is 2 way binding at it's simplest. It will regenerate the table on updating of the `objectArr` array.

Comment: What I want is to get page or table reloaded so that users does not have to refresh the page themselve.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to share your code, but basically you want to do the above, after making an http request if you need help with that you may need to look up a free class on youtube :) - happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I used `window.location.href = './url';` and it worked fine. Atleast it refreshed the page.

Answer (score -1):

```
html : 

<p (click)="deleteUser(item.id)" title="Delete">delete</p>


ts :

ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(res => {
    this.usertable = res;
    }
}

deleteUser(id) {
       this.httpService.delete(this.url_deleteUser + id).subscribe(
       data => {
          this.getUser = JSON.stringify(data);
          this.userService.getUser().subscribe(res => this.usertable = res)
          this.ngOnInit();
       })
  }
```

Comment: you can use `ngOnInit()` method for redirect your page

Comment: The ngOnInit isn't a function that should be called programmatically. Only Angular should handle that logic in the lifecycle. Secondly, try to avoid subscribing inside another subscription. Either use rxjs operators (mergeMap, switchMap,...) or create a new function with that logic and invoke that function.